# Active Directory - Limited collection size using System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices

Im using c# ,

I have over 2000 attributes for  specific Dn

Code :
 var seacher = DirectorySearcher.FindOne();
On doing searcher.Properties.Count()
I get only 1500 items when actualy i have 2500 items .

by saying items i mean attibute.

Did anyone had the same problem ?

Amit.

Answer (score 0):

It will not load all of the attributes. If you need specific attributes, add the attribute names to the [PropertiesToLoad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload(v=vs.110).aspx) collection.

Comment: The problem is that i have an attribute by the name of member which might repeat many times  (like 2500) ☺.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you update your question with the code you have now?

Comment: You can change the sensitive parts (like your domain name).

Comment: The member attribute is used for groups and contains a collection of accounts that are a member of that group. Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem guys ,   before i used the properties as collection using foreach  now i work with GetEnumerator,  it seems that there is paging behind the scene which MoveNext fetching the next page while iterating the collecion not paging.  Qq